# nHibernate NotSupportedException When Joining Projections

Tags: c#, nhibernate

We experience an unexpected behavior of the NHibernate LINQ provider. We try to join two entities and select a projection each which sometimes results in a `NotSupportedException`.

If the projection is defined in the `from` clause of the query, the query can be compiled. Example:

```
var query = from team in session.Query<TeamEntity>()
                    .Select(team => new TeamModel
                    {
                        TeamId = team.Id,
                        Shortname = team.Shortname
                    })
                        join player in session.Query<PlayerEntity>()
                            on team.TeamId equals player.TeamId
                        select new PlayerModel
                        {
                            PlayerId = player.Id,
                            TeamId = team.TeamId,
                            Shortname = team.Shortname,
                            Name = player.Name
                        };

            query.ToList();
```

The statement above compiles into the following SQL statement (generated names replaced):

```
select player.Player_Id, team.Team_Id, team.Shortname, player.Name
from DalTest_Team team, DalTest_Player player 
where player.Team_Id=team.Team_Id
```

If the projection is defined in the `join` clause of the query, the query **cannot** be compiled. Example:

```
var query = from player in session.Query<PlayerEntity>()
                        join team in session.Query<TeamEntity>()
                .Select(team => new TeamModel
                {
                    TeamId = team.Id,
                    Shortname = team.Shortname
                })
                    on player.TeamId equals team.TeamId
                        select new PlayerModel
                        {
                            PlayerId = player.Id,
                            TeamId = team.TeamId,
                            Shortname = team.Shortname,
                            Name = player.Name
                        };

            query.ToList();
```

We do not understand why there would be a difference whether the projection is part of the `from` or part of the `join` statement. Is there any technical reason for this behavior?

You might ask why we would want to define a projection and join based on the projection later on. In our desired case we want to **decouple** business areas of our application. These parts should not know about each other's entities. Also, there could be more than two business areas involved which means that the approach with the projection in the `from` clause does not completely solve our problem.

1. Is this a bug?
2. Are there any other ways to accomplish our goals?

There is a fully functional unit test project in the following GitHub repository. All required dependencies including SQLite can be restored using NuGet.

https://github.com/claudiobernasconi/NHibernateProjectionJoins

Comment: My guess would be that the first will perform two DB queries and join the result sets in memory.  The second will attempt to directly translate this into SQL and I expect the LINQ Provider will not be able to deal with this...  The QueryOver API may be able to do what you want, but I always found it far more difficult to use than standard LINQ.

Comment: On a side note, If you want to decouple the DB access from the business logic then neither of these is doing that IMO.  you should get the data from the DB in the most efficient form possible, then transform it as a whole rather than trying to join a projection directly to an entity like this.  I tend to have a service layer between the Data layer and Business logic layer to do this.

Comment: @GPW Thanks for your response. I edited the original question and included the generated SQL statement. As you can see nHibernate correctly generates the join and does not execute the join in memory. Any more thoughts why the second approach might not work?